# Link with php anchor and hash

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to echo a html link and add a php anchor and a hash anchor.

```
<?php 
echo '<a href="test.php?page='.$i.'#hash">'.$i.'</a>';
?>
```

PHP echoes the link correctly, but after clicking on it, the browser cares only about the hash anchor. If I manually type the link in url, it runs correctly.
Is there a way how to trick the browser to accept both, php anchor and hash anchor?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: What do you mean by the browser only cares about the hash anchor?

Comment: php don't get the `?page=2`

Comment: Give a live example, this scheme should work fine

Comment: Is the $i really defined?

Comment: Yes, it's defined. I'll try to use a POST request instead of GET.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (is_numeric($i)){echo '<a href="test.php?page='.$i.'#hash">'.$i.'</a>';}
else {echo 'value of i is not numeric<br>';}
if (!isset($i)){echo 'i has not been assigned ANY value at all<br>';}
```